# How to resolve object from django ForeignKey Field

Tags: django

I try to traverse django objects in a generic way-

I can't get the related object:

```
# field_names has the names of some fields of object

for field_name in field_names:
    field = object._meta.get_field_by_name(field_name)

    if isinstance(field[0], ForeignKey):
        related = getattr(object, field[0].get_attname())
```

Related then holds the primary key value.

But how do i access the object? What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
field = object._meta.get_field_by_name(field_name)
if isinstance(field[0], ForeignKey):
    fkey = {}
    fkey['name'] = field[0].rel.get_related_field().name
    fkey['value'] =  getattr(object, field[0].get_attname())

    related = field[0].rel.to._default_manager.get(**{fkey['name']: fkey['value']})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the underlying related object from `rel`:

```
field[0].rel.to
```

You can simplify the code a bit by using `get_field()`:

```
for field_name in field_names:
    field = object._meta.get_field(field_name)

    if isinstance(field, ForeignKey):
        related = field.rel.to
```

Comment: then related is the model class, not the related object